# nextjs + getStaticPaths + output: 'export'

Tags: nginx, nextjs, i18n

Есть next приложение, использую i18n, для локализации сайта. Есть необходимость при преходе на ссылку вида /en/url, менять язык сайта. Решил использовать getStaticPaths и getStaticProps. При этом SSR не нужен, используется: output: 'export'. То есть при билде генерятся html'ки.

Структура каталогов получается следующая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге локально все работает, а вот после выгрузке на сервер переход на /en/faq получаю 404, если открываю /[lang]/faq.html, то получаю нужную страницу с fallback локализацией.

Отсюда вопрос, что нужно сделать, чтобы динамический роутинг начал правильно работать? Конфиг nginx? Ещё что-то?